# Linux QT OpenCL basic setup

Tags: linux, qt, opencl

what's the basic setup for Linux to compilie a C/C++ examples from OpenCL SDK?

Comment: more inforamtion please, and what has it to do with Qt at all?

Comment: Don't know why tagged Qt, but if you want to use opencl from qt - see http://labs.trolltech.com/blogs/2010/04/07/using-opencl-with-qt/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get started download the drivers and SDK from your vendor, install both, then build and run the samples.